# Build a class the returns a line graph according to user input

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to built a class that returns a line graph. The data is country-wise and the class should o be able to return a figure (line graph) with everything from one country to as many as the user wants.

I'm new to classes. Below I started to build some simple methods, one for a one country line graph and one for a two country comparison.

I wonder, what is the smartest way to create a class that can return anything from one line (one country) to as many lines as the user wants?

```
class explore_data():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')

    
    def plot1(self, country):
        df1=self.df.set_index('date')
        df1 = df1[df1['country']==country]
        plt.plot(df1['var'], label = 'label')
        plt.legend()
        plt.title(' {}'.format(country))
        plt.show()
    
    def plot2(self, country1, country2):
        #df1=self.df.set_index('date')
        plt.plot(df[df['country'] == country1].set_index('date')['var'], label=country1)
        plt.plot(df[df['country'] == country2].set_index('date')['var'], label=country2)
        plt.legend()
        plt.title('{} vs {}'.format(country1, country2))
        plt.show()
```

Comment: _I wonder, what is the smartest way to create a class that can return anything from one line (one country) to as many lines as the user wants?_ is asking for an opinion, and questions asking for an opinion are off-topic. Please rephrase the question to ask something specific. Also, this is not a complete [mre] without sufficient sample data. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) & [Don't advise on off-topic questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/)

Comment: FYI, answers belong as answers, not as edits to the question. I've moved the solution you edited in to a proper answer of its own this time, but please post it as an answer yourself from the get-go in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by OP moved from question to answer:

> I found a solution using *args (*countries) and for loop within a
> method. That provides the user with the flexibility I was looking for.
> Sometimes it's better to think before posting a question.
>
> ````
> 'Fr', 'Fr', 'Mexico', 'Mexico', 'Mexico', 'Mexico'],
>                    'date':['2020-01','2020-02', '2020-03', '2020-04','2020-01','2020-02', '2020-03',
> '2020-04','2020-01','2020-02', '2020-03', '2020-04'],
>              'n':[1,2,3,4,2,3,3,5, 2, 4, 4, 4]})
>
> df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m')
>
> def plot2(*countries):
>         for i in countries:
>             plt.plot(df[df['country'] == i].set_index('date')['n'], label=i)
>             
>         plt.legend()
>         plt.show()
>
> plot2('UK', 'Fr', 'Mexico') ```
> ````